# Div moves when adding text, word-wrap doesn't work

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a div for few images (it worked so far), the div for some text on the right side and other div for text on the bottom as well.
When I add text into the `missedletters` div it somehow goes down not sure why. I think there might be something with `display:inline-block`
that causes the mess, but I can't figure out what is it.

The CSS that matters:

```css
body {
  background-color: #303030;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-size: 28px;
}

body .arena {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 11.5%;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.poorguy {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 12px;
  min-width: 360px;
  /* not sure if shouldn't be longer, but fits into it*/
  min-height: 300px;
  /* so i'll check it out in the process*/
  bottom: 0px;
}

.missedletters {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  min-height: 320px;
  min-width: 190px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.correctletters {
  min-height: 80px;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="arena">
      <div class="poorguy">
      </div>
      <div class="missedletters">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you please elaborate on where exactly the problem is? When you add text to `missedletters`, it starts from halfway down the container. Would you like the container to **grow** in size to accommodate any text entered? `poorguy` simply inserts text at the top of the container; is this intended? You mention a div to the 'right', but I'm not sure which this is?

Comment: `missedletters` is suppoed to grow in size to accomodate any text entered, and the poorguy's purpose will be to hold pictures(as I wrote it works). corrected letters is supposed to hold text aswell, but it's working fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a max-width/width to your `missedletters` div. You could use `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block`;

Comment: I tried using `float:left;`, but it messed  up placement of my `poorguy` div , however using max-width and changing min-width did help.